# JSF : immediate true causes problem in searching the product

Tags: jsf

I am facing the problem of immediate = "true" in my project.

I have applied immediate = "true" on search commandLink to By Pass the validation.
but it affects the search functionality.

it does not execute the search method...

what is the problem can anyone explaine...

is there any way to bypass the validation and search the product without using immediate="true"

Thanking in advance

Comment: Please elaborate the functional requirements. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. What validation are you talking about? `required="true"` or so? Why is it then there in first instance?

Comment: i have applied the custom validator of jsf on text field. so i cant do anything if validation violate.because of that i have put immediate="true" on search button. but after that search method could not be execute...

Answer (score 3):

Your functional requirement is still unclear (which brings those contra-questions: Why is the validator there? Why/when do you want to bypass this? Do you have multiple buttons? etc..etc..), so I can't be of more help than recommending  you to get yourself through this article to learn about the why of the `immediate` attribute and to help yourself with the problem: [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html).

Here's a summary of relevance:

> ### [Okay, when should I use the immediate attribute?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#WhenShouldIUseTheImmediateAttribute)
>
> If it isn't entirely clear yet, here's a summary, complete with real world use examples when they may be beneficial:
>
> - If set in `UIInput`(s) only, the process validations phase will be taken place in apply request values phase instead. Use this to prioritize validation for the `UIInput` component(s) in question. When validation/conversion fails for any of them, the non-immediate components won't be validated/converted.
> - If set in `UICommand` only, the apply request values phase until with update model values phases will be skipped for any of the `UIInput` component(s). Use this to skip the entire processing of the form. E.g. "Cancel" or "Back" button.
> - If set in both `UIInput` and `UICommand` components, the apply request values phase until with update model values phases will be skipped for any of the `UIInput` component(s) which does not have this attribute set. Use this to skip the processing of the entire form expect for certain fields (with immediate). E.g. "Password forgotten" button in a login form with a required but non-immediate password field.